# How to get data from a JSON file for a header in Nuxt 3

Tags: javascript, json, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

[image]

(Above data from json)

I need to get the data for site header from JSON in Nuxt 3.

I can't get the data like "api.title". My Example code:

```
    <script setup>
const { data: api } = await useFetch(useRuntimeConfig().public.home)

useServerSeoMeta({
    title: api.title,
    description: 'This is my amazing site, let me tell you all about it.',
})



</script>
```

How to get data from JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `useServerSeoMeta` exist in nuxt 3. Have you tried using `useHead` composable? This composable allows you to manage your head tag programmatically and reactive. More details on the [documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-head)

Example usage, display meta title based on the data response from `useFetch` composable

```js
useHead({
  title: data.value[0].title,
});
```

To see it in action, I created a stackblitz example. The data is from the server folder but accessed it by using the `useRuntimeConfig` composable. I based it on your codes.
Stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-uexjsa?file=pages/index.vue

Inspect element the example to see the meta title updated. Here is the screenshot
[image]